# function with parameter for addItem in spreadsheet menu using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need at each open of the spreadsheets, to check for the available sheets in the spreadsheet and make a list add-on that Go to Specific sheet through click in the item list

The number of the sheets will be large and added dynamically through working

i'm blocking currently on making this "dummy" function take parameters so, when called it should open the sheet by its index

```html
function onOpen() {
  var monthPlanShortcuts = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Month Plan Shortcuts");
  var gotoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Go to sheet");
  // get properties to know who is the editor
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  if (sheets.length > 1) {
    for (var index = 0; index< sheets.length;index++)
    {
      var currentIndex = userProperties.setProperty("index",index);
      gotoSheet.addItem(sheets[index].getName(),"dummy");
    }
  }
  monthPlanShortcuts
    .addItem('View Current Week Plan', 'gotoCurrentWeek')
    .addItem('Go to Specific Week', 'gotoSpecificWeek')
  .addSeparator()
  .addSubMenu(gotoSheet)
  .addToUi();
}
```

any suggestions??

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not pass a parameter value from the function in `.addItem('Title of Menu Item', 'function name')` to the function being called.  So, there is no way to do what you want **in one step** from a menu.  You would need to open a dialog box, or sidebar from the menu.  Or open a sidebar automatically when the spreadsheet opens, and with HTML and JavaScript you can create something that will associate the sheet name with whatever code you want to run.

Comment: @SandyGood thank you but isn't there any workaround like,
1- generating functions with the a specific name and mark its functionality to active the sheet
or
2- getting the index of the list an the index will refer to the sheet index as well
or 
3- unique function that take the function name and transfer to function with parameters

Comment: I don't know of any work around.

Answer (score 4):

There is a hackish workaround:

Dynamically create top-level functions, and then refer to them when adding the menu items.

Example:

```js
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function onOpen() {
  let menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Dynamic entries");
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var sheet of ss.getSheets()) {
    let id = sheet.getSheetId();
    let funName = "dynamicFun" + id;
    menu.addItem(sheet.getName() + "(" + id + ")", funName)
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

for (var sheet of SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()) {
  let id = sheet.getSheetId();
  let funName = "dynamicFun" + id;
  this[funName] = function() { myRealFun(id); };
}

function myRealFun(id) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("" + id + " was pressed");
}
```